# modifying div visibility when ajax involved

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am beginner, and having problem making a change in this code.

This example gets stock quote (plus day's low and high) from php file via Ajax,
embedding result in page itself after indicating progress with an animated GIF.

HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

        // an XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = null;

        /*
         * void
         * quote()
         *
         * Gets a quote.
         */
        function quote()
        {
            // instantiate XMLHttpRequest object
            try
            {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            // handle old browsers
            if (xhr == null)
            {
                alert("Ajax not supported by your browser!");
                return;
            }

            // construct URL
            var url = "quote4.php?symbol=" + document.getElementById("symbol").value;

            // hide quote div (it'll hide the previous content, if exist) #TBD
            document.getElementById("quote").visible = "false";

            // show progress
            document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";



            // get quote
            xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        /*
         * void
         * handler()
         *
         * Handles the Ajax response.
         */

        function handler()
        {
            // only handle requests in "loaded" state
            if (xhr.readyState == 4)  
            {
                // show quote div #TBD
                document.getElementById("quote").visible = "true";

                // hide progress
                document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "none";

                if (xhr.status == 200)

                  // set quote div with response received
                  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                else
                    alert("Error with Ajax call!");
            }
        }

    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="quote(); return false;">
      Symbol: <input id="symbol" type="text">
      <br><br>
      <div id="progress" style="display: none;">
        <img alt="Please Wait" src="19-0.gif">
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div id="quote"></div>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Get Quote">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP File:

```
    <?

    // pretend server is slow
    sleep(2);

    // try to get quote
    $handle = @fopen("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={$_GET['symbol']}&f=e1l1hg", "r");
    if ($handle !== FALSE)
    {
        $data = fgetcsv($handle);
        if ($data !== FALSE && $data[0] == "N/A")
        {
            print("Price: {$data[1]}");
            print("<br />");
            print("High: {$data[2]}");
            print("<br />");
            print("Low: {$data[3]}");
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

**Problem:**

i am attempting to hide div 'quote', and then setting it to visible when the response text it received.

But it's not:

- hiding the quote div when quote() is executed.
  under "// hide quote div" comment.
- showing the quote div when response text is received in handler function. 
  under "// show quote div" comment.

can someone pls help me fix it.

Note: code is from a Harvard University open course lecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `visible` property of DOM elements. To hide an element, set its `display` style to `none`:

```
document.getElementById("quote").style.display = "none";
```

to make it visible again:

```
document.getElementById("quote").style.display = null;
```

Comment: thanks @barmar . 
it fixed the issue. 
And works better than the .style.visibility property because it doesn't take any space when it's hidden. Looks good on UI. 

on contrary .style.visibility keeps block at the background even and user can observe the space.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the whole difference between visibility and display. Occasionally visibility is useful in tabular output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//to hide it
document.getElementById("quote").style.visibility = 'hidden'

//to show it
document.getElementById("quote").style.visibility = 'visible'
```